# Thread start was failing in the Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, syntax, token

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
    public void run()
    {
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        finally{    
            Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.askselva.simple.MENU");
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
        }
        
    }   
};
th.start();               //Error -1
```

> Error 1 : Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after
> this token

Comment: You can't have this statement "just hanging there". This is not PHP... It is not very clear what you tried to achieve with this, please add some details to clarify on what you want to do.

Comment: th.start(); put in onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

Your `th.start();` statement should be present in some method in your `Activity` class. You can't just have that lying around somewhere in the activity.

In your case, it could go in the `OnCreate()` method, but the thread creation must be done before you `start` the thread there.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be a comment?

Comment: This is the answer to the question. It needs to go in some method! Why should it be a comment?

Comment: The answer would be to tell _in which_ method it has to go. This is _the problem_ not the _solution_.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you shouldn't have your `th.start()` outside your class methods. You can't put it randomly inside your class like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
package com.askselva.simple;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Splash extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle selvaLovesKumar) {
        super.onCreate(selvaLovesKumar);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSong=MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.airtel);
        ourSong.start();

        Thread th = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{    
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.askselva.simple.MENU");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }   
    };
    th.start();  
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    ourSong.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help u...

in onCreate Method

```
Thread currentThread = new Thread(this);
currentThread.start();
```

after on create

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //don't forget to deal with the Exception !!!!!
    }
}

private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() {
     public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {      
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),****.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this :)

```
package com.askselva.simple;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Splash extends Activity{
MediaPlayer ourSong;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle selvaLovesKumar){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(selvaLovesKumar);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong=MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.airtel);
    ourSong.start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()){
      public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{    
            Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.askselva.simple.MENU");
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
        }
      } 
    }.start();        
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPause(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    ourSong.release();
  }
 }
```